# Query to be improved

Tags: mysql

I have the following query and it is working perfectly but it is taking too long to execute. How can I improve it.

My Query:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM chapter 
      LEFT JOIN page 
         ON chapter.chapterID = page.chapterID 
   WHERE 
          chapter.lectureID = 5 
      AND chapter.category LIKE 'Intermediate' 
   GROUP BY 
      page.pageID,
      page.chapterID
```

Comment: If only you could present the table structure in a clearer way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Use equals instead of LIKE. Then remove your GROUP BY, because it's useless.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM chapter
LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID = page.chapterID
WHERE chapter.lectureID = 5 AND chapter.category = 'Intermediate'
```